# Freeradius Authentication via REST + MSCHAPv2

Tags: freeradius

I'm trying to configure Freeradius to make a REST call to authenticate users in the inner tunnel.

Without the REST call, I have user `bob` in the `users` file and the entry

```
bob    Cleartext-Password := "test"
```

This by itself works as expected when the test user tries to authenticate.

Now, I have configured the REST endpoint to return the json:

```json
{
  "Cleartext-Password": "test"
}
```

and I have changed the config in inner-tunnel:

```
authorize {
  ...
  rest
  # files
  ...
}

authenticate {
  ...
  Auth-Type MS-CHAP {
    mschap
  }
  Auth-Type rest {
    rest
  }
  ...
```

This fails, and the relavant logs are:

```
2020-09-22T16:14:30.698-04:00   (7) rest: Status : 200 (OK)
2020-09-22T16:14:30.698-04:00   (7) rest: Type : json (application/json)
2020-09-22T16:14:30.698-04:00   (7) rest: Parsing attribute "Cleartext-Password"
2020-09-22T16:14:30.698-04:00   (7) rest: EXPAND test
2020-09-22T16:14:30.698-04:00   (7) rest: --> test
2020-09-22T16:14:30.698-04:00   (7) rest: Cleartext-Password := "test"
2020-09-22T16:14:30.703-04:00   (7) [rest] = updated
2020-09-22T16:14:30.703-04:00   (7) [expiration] = noop
2020-09-22T16:14:30.703-04:00   (7) [logintime] = noop
2020-09-22T16:14:30.703-04:00   (7) [pap] = noop
2020-09-22T16:14:30.703-04:00   (7) } # authorize = updated
2020-09-22T16:14:30.703-04:00   (7) Found Auth-Type = mschap
2020-09-22T16:14:30.703-04:00   (7) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
2020-09-22T16:14:30.703-04:00   (7) authenticate {
2020-09-22T16:14:30.703-04:00   (7) mschap: WARNING: No Cleartext-Password configured. Cannot create NT-Password
```

I'm sure what I'm missing here is quite simple, but I'm a radius noob and this is as far as I've managed to get by fiddling around.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue! Apparently the returned json needed a small tweak.

Instead of:

```
{
    "Cleartext-Password": "test",
}
```

It should have been:

```
{
    "control:Cleartext-Password": "test",
}
```

I found this buried in an answer to a related question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57662829/2345647)

If anyone can point me to documentation that states this and maybe even explains why, I will upvote you so hard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658080/freeradius-users-operators/17968867#17968867