# Request without User-Password attribute for rest module even in ttls inner tunnel

Tags: freeradius

So I came from
[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648427/freeradius-request-without-user-password-attribute-for-rest-module) and trying approach 1.

Here is how I got here:

- Configured `sites-available/default` like:

```
authorize {
    eap
}
authenticate {
    eap
}
```

and `sites-available/inner-tunnel` like:

```
authorize {
    update control {
        MS-CHAP-Use-NTLM-Auth := No
    }
    if (&User-Password) {
        update control {
            Auth-Type = rest
        }
    }
}
authenticate {
    Auth-Type rest {
        rest {
            updated = 1
        }
        if (updated) {
            ok
        }
    }
    Auth-Type MS-CHAP {
        mschap
    }
}
```

and `mods-available/eap` like:

```
default_eap_type = ttls
```

(this is the only line I modified, in section `eap{}`)

And now I still get no `User-Password` while using iPhone to connect to the AP, connection output in [pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/7b9DHyKDRx/).
The output is of two tests using iPhone and PC, each tried connect to the AP with username "a" and password "b", this is actually wrong, but iPhone didn't send to radius server the "User-Password" while the PC did. And iPhone was rejected because it didn't contain a password, while the PC was rejected because the password is literally wrong(successfully connected on the PC if the password is correct).

Anything I did was wrong? How to correct the configuration?